# How does one prove this equation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, stirling-numbers

How does one prove the following equation , I am getting confused about this, I can't seem to find any proving technique, I tried plugging in the Stirling's formula for factorials but to no avail -

$\binom{2n}{n}$ = $\theta(4^n/n^(1/2))$

Comment: $k$ must have some close relation to $n$. Otherwise, it's wrong, for fixed $k$, we have $\binom{n+1}{2k} = \Theta(n^{2k})$.

Comment: Perhaps it's supposed to be $\binom{n+1}{2n}$?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I just modified the problem, inexperienced using MathJax :)

Comment: For that, Stirling's formula does yield the result almost immediately.

Comment: How, can you explain

Comment: @DanielFischer : just plugging in Stirling's formula doesn't yield anything to me

Answer (score 2):

Per Stirling's formula,

$$k! \sim \sqrt{2\pi k} \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k,$$

we obtain

$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi 2n}(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}}{2\pi n (n^ne^{-n})^2} = \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}} = \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$